# Solution of differential equation by by an iterative method

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, algorithm

Let $y^{\prime\prime}(t)+y^{2}(t)-t^{4}-2=0$, where $0\leq t\leq 1$. The boundary conditions are $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=1$ and so its  exact solution is $y(t)=t^{2}$. Now I want to compute the solution by the following method; $x_{n}=x_{n-1}+\alpha_{n-1}\int_{0}^{t}s(1-t)[x^{\prime\prime}_{n-1}(s)+x^{2}_{n-1}(s)-s^{4}-2]ds+\alpha_{n-1}\int_{t}^{1}t(1-s)[x^{\prime\prime}_{n-1}(s)+x^{2}_{n-1}(s)-s^{4}-2]ds$ $n=0,1,2,..$ where the initial guess is $x_{0}(t)=t$. I have set the following code for $t=0.5$ so the exact solution in this case is $y(t)=0.5^{2}=0.25$ and $x_{0}(t)=t=0.5$. Now I set the following code:

```
Clear[x,s, T, a]

a[n_] := a[n] = 0.70
t=0.5
x[0] = 0.5;
x[n_] := x[n] = x[n-1]+a[n-1]*Integrate[s(1-t)(x''[n-1]+(x[n-1])^2-s^4-2),{s,0,t}]
+a[n-1]*Integrate[t(1-s)(x''[n-1]+(x[n-1])^2-s^4-2),{s,t,1}]
NumberForm[a1 = {Table[x[i], {i, 0, 7}]}, 5]
```

and when I run the mathemtica I found some error. Please help me.

Comment: You define x as a sequence. But x'' does only exists for a continuous function, not a sequence.

Comment: Dear, I have try the problem too much and in different ways, but I cant succeeded.

Comment: A discrete approximation of x'' would be: x''[n]= x[n-1]-2 x[n]+x[n+1]

Comment: BTW, I wonder if the posted iterative method bears a name or not.

Answer (score 2):

Below the trick is to use [`Interpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interpolation.html), which can transform discrete values into a continuous function, so that the latter can be [`Derivative`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Derivative.html)d directly and the difficulty mentioned by @DaneilHuber in the comment is overcome.

```
Clear[ndSolveByIterate]
ndSolveByIterate[tsamplings_, xinitfunc_] := 
Module[{xinit = xinitfunc /@ tsamplings, α = .7, Δx, iterate, zero = 1.*^-4},
  Δx[t_, xlast_] := 
  Module[{xfunc = Interpolation[{tsamplings, xlast}\[Transpose]], integrand},
    integrand[s_] := xfunc''[s] + xfunc[s]^2 - s^4 - 2;
    α (NIntegrate[s (1 - t) integrand[s], {s, 0, t}] + 
       NIntegrate[t (1 - s) integrand[s], {s, t, 1}])
  ];
  iterate = # + ParallelTable[Δx[t, #], {t, tsamplings + zero}] &;
  NestWhile[iterate, xinit, Mean[Abs[# - #2]] > zero &, 2]
]
```

BTW, replacing [`NestWhile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhile.html) in the last step with [`NestWhileList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestWhileList.html), one can see datas generated in each iterative step.

[image]

Comment: thanks dear. But I cant see the method im suggested in your code. Please

Comment: Hi @Junaid , it is there. If you look at the part defining `Δx` closely enough, you will find it.

Comment: Dear  @Αλέξανδρος Ζεγγ, CAN I OBTAIN VALUES USING NumberForm[a1 = {Table[x[i], {i, 0, 7}]}, 5] FROM YOUR CODE?

Answer (score 2):

There is no iteration in your code, and you're specifying the index of `x` as its variable, so the integrations inside the recursive formula will try to integrate over the index, which isn't correct. You could try the following:

```
x[0] = t;
h = 0.7;
Do[
    n = i;
    xs = x[n] /. t -> s;
    f = D[xs, {s, 2}] + xs^2 - s^4 - 2;
    x[n + 1] = x[n] + h*Integrate[s*(1 - t)*f, {s, 0, t}] + h*Integrate[t*(1 - s)*f, {s, t, 1}];
    Clear[n, xs, f];
, {i, 0, 7}]
```

You should expect that this might take some time, because the order of `x` and the number of terms increase exponentially with the order of `2`, which also means that you're gonna need a very high numeric precision to compute properly. You can set the global precision by adding the following in the beginning:

```
$MinPrecision = 200;
$PreRead = (# /. s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] && Precision@ToExpression@s == MachinePrecision :> s <> "`200." &);
```

For my PC, it took less than a second to get `x[7]`, but for some reason `x[8]` (and higher) is taking forever (most likely due to precision overhead). Nevertheless, it yields the correct answer:

```
TableForm@Table[x[i] /. t -> 1/2, {i,0,7}]
```

[image]

---

**UPDATE.** If you prefer not to care about precision entirely and compute everything with infinite precision, then just define every number as rational form (such as `h = 0.7` to `h = 7/10`). In such a case...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear @Kim thanks for your kind help. When I paste the code you suggested (x[0]=t upto {i,0,7}] then I get nothing. When I add TableForm@Table[x[i]/. t:>1/2,{i,0,7] then i get 1/2. x[1], x[2],...,x[7] and I can get numerical values. Please explain and hel. thanks

Comment: @Junaid Oh, I forgot to add `;` at the end of the recursive formula. Now it's gonna work; please try again.

Comment: Thanks Dear Kim. Your suggested code now runs in my mathemtica. I have add the term x[(n+1)_]:= before x[n+1]. However, now the code works well for x8 but fails to go furhter. I have also add  precision by adding them as u suggested. So what should I do next to successed in the furhter iterations.

Comment: Thanks Dears
Daniel Shin Kin for your kind help. I will b more thankful if u provide me a help to my new question at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264403/a-method-for-endpoints-in-mathemtica