# How to compute higher iterations in mathemtica

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization, algorithm

I have  the equation $u^{\prime\prime}(t)+u^{2}(t)-t^{4}-2=0$ such that $0\leq t\leq 1$and also I have   $u(0)=0$ as well as  $u(1)=1$. Noe the exact solution of the equation is  $u(t)=t^{2}$. Now I want to compute the solution by the modified Mann method;
\begin{equation*}
 x_{n+1}=x_{n}+h\int_{0}^{t}s(1-t)[x^{\prime\prime}_{n}(s)+x^{2}_{n}(s)-s^{4}-2]ds+h\int_{t}^{1}t(1-s)[x^{\prime\prime}_{n}(s)+x^{2}_{n}(s)-s^{4}-2]ds
\end{equation*}
with the starting value $x_{0}(t)=t$. If  $t=0.5$ then the exact solution of the equation will be $u(t)=0.5^{2}=0.25$ and so the starting value will be $x_{0}(t)=t=0.5$. My code is

```
x[0] = t;
h = 0.7;
Do[n = i;
xs = x[n] /. t -> s;
f = D[xs, {s, 2}] + xs^2 - s^4 - 2;
x[(n + 1) _] := x[n + 1] = x[n] + h*Integrate[s*(1 - t)*f, {s, 0, t}] + h*Integrate[t*(1 - s)*f, {s, t, 1}];
Clear[n, xs, f];, {i, 0, 8}];
NumberForm[a1 = {Table[x[i] /. t -> (0.5), {i, 0, 7}]}, 5]
```

When I run my mathetica, I found a sequence of numbers as

```
0.5,0.33922,...,0.25005
```

Now for more than 9 iterations I see some error code. I also tried the following before my codes, but cant find the aim.

```
$MinPrecision = 200;
$PreRead = (# /. s_String /; StringMatchQ[s, NumberString] && Precision@ToExpression@s ==MachinePrecision :> s <> "`200." &);
```

I would be very thankfull If any one improve my code (or suggest a new code in new way) so that I find other iterations above 9,10,11, ... and so on.

Comment: Your `x[(n + 1) _]` makes no sense, it is not a proper pattern. As `n` has an integer value here, simply use `x[n+1] = x[n] + h*Integrate...` without using patterns.

Comment: dear @Roman thanks for ur kind reply. I add this terms to improve the speed of iteration. If we remove this term, the mathetica finds the iteration slowly but values are same.

Comment: my problem is here too run more iterations 9 and so on

Comment: The code in this post should not appear without attribution to the respondent from a previous thread who provided it. That warrants a downvote.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your expressions get exponentially large with increasing $n$. An efficient implementation with [partial memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/200998/26598):

```
h = 0.7;

Clear[x];
x[0] = Function[t, t];
x[n_Integer?Positive] := x[n] = Function[t, Evaluate[Expand[
  x[n - 1][t] + 
  h*Integrate[s(1-t)(x[n-1]''[s]+x[n-1][s]^2-s^4-2), {s, 0, t}] + 
  h*Integrate[t(1-s)(x[n-1]''[s]+x[n-1][s]^2-s^4-2), {s, t, 1}]]]]
```

Let's look at some results:

```
x[0][t]
(*    t    *)

x[1][t]
(*    0. + 0.335 t + 0.7 t^2 - 0.0583333 t^4 + 0.0233333 t^6    *)

x[2][t]
(*    0. + 0.110309 t + 0.91 t^2 - 0.0240465 t^4 - 0.016415 t^5 +
      0.0189 t^6 + 0.000651389 t^7 + 0.00102083 t^8 - 0.000151991 t^9 -
      0.00028054 t^10 + 0.000014436 t^12 - 2.09402*10^-6 t^14    *)
```

You can see that this is a polynomial in $t$ of order $2^{n+2}-2$. So for $n=9$ you'll have a polynomial of order 2046; is this what you want? If not, we could for example chop off all polynomial contributions that are smaller than a cutoff $\delta$:

```
h = 0.7;
δ = 10^-20;
Clear[x];
x[0] = Function[t, t];
x[n_Integer?Positive] := x[n] = Function[t, Evaluate[
  Chop[Expand[
    x[n-1][t] +
    h*Integrate[s(1-t)(x[n-1]''[s]+x[n-1][s]^2-s^4-2), {s, 0, t}] + 
    h*Integrate[t(1-s)(x[n-1]''[s]+x[n-1][s]^2-s^4-2), {s, t, 1}]],
  δ]]]
```

This is much faster:

```
Table[x[n][0.5], {n, 0, 20}]
(*    {0.5, 0.339219, 0.280943, 0.260626, 0.253639, 0.251246, 0.250427,
       0.250146, 0.25005, 0.250017, 0.250006, 0.250002, 0.250001,
       0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25}    *)
```

Comment: The code OP states as *his code* is a [direct copy and paste of my answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264314/solution-of-differential-equation-by-by-an-iterative-method/264340#264340) to his previous question. And in the answer I mentioned the exact same thing. The problem with cut-off is that it yields limited (or downright wrong) result because the method heavily relies on those tiny minuscule add-ups. That's why even after 8 iterations, the value is still far from 2.5 (truth value).

Comment: @Roman Thanks for your inspiring answer. There is a little error, integrand should be ` (x[n-1]''[s]+ x[n-1][s]^2-s^4-2)` (not ` (x[n-1]''[s]+2x[n-1][s]^2-s^4-2)` )

Comment: @UlrichNeumann thanks & thanks, corrected.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem of basis functions choice to represent solution. The simplest basis in this case is `{1,t,t^2,...,t^n}` (Taylor series). We can restrict maximal power from the beginning as follows

```
nmax = 14; var = Table[t^n, {n, 0, nmax}];
h = 7/10; nn = 15; x[0] = t;
Do[
  xs[n] = x[n] /. t -> s;
  g[n] = D[xs[n], {s, 2}] + xs[n]^2 - s^4 - 2; 
  in1 = Integrate[s*g[n], s]; in2 = Integrate[g[n], s] - in1; 
  int1 = in1 /. s -> t; int2 = (in2 /. s -> 1) - (in2 /. s -> t);
  xn = x[n] + h*(1 - t) int1 + h*t int2; lst = CoefficientList[xn, t];
   x[n + 1] = 
   If[Length[lst] < Length[var], xn, Take[lst, Length[var]] . var];
  , {n, 0, nn}];
```

Solution in the point `t=1/2`

```
Table[N[x[i] /. t -> 1/2, 30], {i, 0, nn}]

{0.5`, 0.33921875`, 0.2809426617675349`, 0.26062635193160333`, \
0.2536391058021099`, 0.25124579177605266`, 0.25042664666458403`, \
0.2501461896648886`, 0.25005010293913515`, 0.25001715807367814`, \
0.25000585393695235`, 0.2500019724479996`, 0.25000063876358225`, \
0.2500001802169856`, 0.250000022466089`, 0.24999996816592682`}
```

Absolute error in the logarithmic scale

```
LogPlot[Abs[t^2 - x[nn]], {t, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"t", "Absolute error"}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

We also can solve this problem with zero absolute error using the Euler wavelets colocation method described in our [paper](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/10/3/165) and on my [page](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2457908) as follows

```
eq = D[x[s], {s, 2}] + x[s]^2 - s^4 - 2 == 0; bc = {x[0] == 0, 
  x[1] == 1}; xs[t_] := t^2;
UE[m_, t_] := EulerE[m, t]
psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^(k/2) Sqrt[2/Pi] UE[m, 2^k t - 2 n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]
PsiE[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
k0 = 3; M0 = 3; nn = 
 Total[With[{k = k0, M = M0}, 
   Flatten[Table[1, {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]]]
dx = 1/(nn);  xl = Table[ l*dx, {l, 0, nn}]; tcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, nn + 1}]; Psijk = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, PsiE[k, M, t1]]; Int1 = 
 With[{k = k0, M = M0}, Integrate[PsiE[k, M, t1], t1]];
Int2 = Integrate[Int1, t1]; Psi[y_] := Psijk /. t1 -> y; 
int1[y_] := Int1 /. t1 -> y; int2[y_] := Int2 /. t1 -> y;
M = nn; var = Array[v, {M}];
X2[t_] := var . Psi[t]; X1[t_] := var . int1[t] + v1; 
X[t_] := var . int2[t] + v1 t + v0;
eqn = Join[
  Table[X2[s] + X[s]^2 - s^4 - 2 == 0, {s, tcol}], {X[0] == 0, 
   X[1] == 1}]; varM = Join[{v0, v1}, var];


sol = FindRoot[eqn, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}]]
```

Visualization numerical solution and error

```
Show[Plot[xs[t], {t, 0, 1}], 
 ListPlot[Table[{t, X[t] /. sol}, {t, tcol}], PlotStyle -> Red]]

ListPlot[Table[xs[t] - X[t] /. sol, {t, tcol}], PlotStyle -> Red, 
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image: Figure 2]

To decries error we use option

```
 sol1 = FindRoot[eqn, Table[{varM[[i]], 1/10}, {i, Length[varM]}], 
   WorkingPrecision -> 100];
```

Error of this solution is zero

```
Table[xs[t] - X[t] /. sol1, {t, tcol}]

Out[]= {0.*10^-103, 0.*10^-102, 0.*10^-102, 0.*10^-102, 0.*10^-101, 
 0.*10^-101, 0.*10^-101, 0.*10^-101, 0.*10^-101, 0.*10^-101, 
 0.*10^-101, 0.*10^-101}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `NestList`you might optimize your code a bit. But you should be aware, that this iteration is symbolically (uses `integrate`) and creates very small numbers :

iterative function

```
iter[f_ (* pure function*)] := 
Block[{h = 0.7 (* optimaler Wert, Konvergenzgeschwindigkeit?*)}, 
Function[t,f[t] + h Integrate[s (1 - t) (f''[s] + f[s]^2 - s^4 - 2), {s, 0, t}] + h Integrate[t (1 - s) (f''[s] + f[s]^2 - s^4 - 2), {s, t, 1}] //Evaluate ]
]
```

iteration starting with `x0[t]== t`

```
sol = Map[#[t] &, NestList[iter, # &, 10]] // Quiet;
```

gives warning message: General::munfl: -1.44299*10^-307+1.42652*10^-307 is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost.

`Plot`shows good convergence

```
Show[Plot[sol , {t, 0, 1}], Plot[t^2, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]]
```

[image]

```
Show[Plot[sol , {t, 0, 1}], Plot[t^2, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]]
```

Comment: Thanks Dear
@Daniel Lichtblau  for ur kind help. I will be thankful if  you provide me a help to my new question at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264403/a-method-for-endpoints-in-mathemtica