# Numerical values of an iterative scheme are different from values in a Paper

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

I want to solve a pde $y^{\prime\prime}(t)=\frac{3}{2}y(t)^{2}$ with boundary conditions $y(0)=4$ and $y(1)=1$. The exact solution of this problem is $y(t)=\frac{4}{(1+t)^{2}}$. Now I want to solve this by an iterative method In the attached Picture [image]

```
δ = 10^-20;
Clear[x];
x[0] = Function[t, 4 - 3 t];
a[n_] := a[n] = 0.5947894739;
x[n_] := x[n] =Function[t,Evaluate[Chop[Expand[x[n - 1][t] + a[n]*Integrate[Expand[s (1 - t) (x[n - 1]''[s] - (1.5) x[n - 1][s]^2)], {s,0, t}] + a[n]*Integrate[Expand[t (1 - s) (x[n - 1]''[s] - (1.5) x[n - 1][s]^2)], {s,t, 1}]], \[Delta]]]];
Table[Abs[x[i][0.5] - x[i + 1][0.5]], {i, 0, 20}]
```

When I run the code I get "3.60822(10^-12) But in the Table it is "8.075267(10^-12)$.

Also for 0.5 the exact solution is 16/9. So that I also tried the following code for absolute error

```
Table[Abs[x[i][0.5] - (16/9)], {i, 0, 20}]
```

In this case I get (4.02495(10^-11) in both the case my answer is very near to the answer given in paper but I want to get the exact answer as given in the paper. This code works very well for some other papers but for this paper the problem is still exists. I also changed the value of delta but cant succeeded. The complete paper is at https://sci-hub.hkvisa.net/10.1016/j.aml.2018.02.016

The authors used Matlab softwhare but I used Mathematica. This post is related with [How to compute higher iterations in mathemtica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264395/how-to-compute-higher-iterations-in-mathemtica) and [Mathematica does not show anything after running for higher iterations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/265618/mathematica-does-not-show-anything-after-running-for-higher-iterations)

Comment: Those appear to be errors due to using machine-precision numbers. You might want to try re-running the code using exact numbers, i.e., substitute 1/2 for 0.5, 3/2 for 1.5, and 5947894739/10^10 for 0.5947894739.  I tried doing that myself, but when the computation didn't finish in 20 min. I gave up, as I needed to do other work in MMA.  You might want to try running your code with exact numbers overnight. [Machine-precision calcs are run on hardware, while MMA's exact calcs require an intervening softeware layer, so are slower.] If you get an answer, you can then numericise the results.

Comment: You could ask the authors what software they used to generate the table. Papers should really include any code they used for generating results in the appendix, or make that available.

Comment: Dear @Nasser they used Matlab software I discussed with them.

Comment: Change the `Table` to a `Do` and print the results as you go (after following the advice from @theorist).  I get $i$ from 0 to 9 to go real fast but then things slow down considerably for 10 to 20 for `Table[Abs[x[i][0.5] - (16/9)], {i, 0, 20}]`.

Comment: Dear @theorist thanks for your kind hints. I run the code according to your suggestions but I obtained the same answars.

Comment: Did you get symbolic answers that you had to numericise, or did you get numerical answers?  [Just as an example:  symbolic = Sqrt[2]/3; numeric = 0.471405.] I ask because if you got the latter, it means you missed converting one of the decimals to an exact number (which sometimes happens).

Comment: Dear @theorist when I changed all the values then I get very lengthy calculations

Comment: And when you then numericised the results from these lengthy calculations (e.g., by doing N[result, 20] did you get the same answers as you got originally?

Comment: The paper says the value `8.075267(−12)` is for `t=0.5`. Are you sure you comparing at your result 3.60822(10^-12) at same `t`? Also you use `Chop`. How do you know Matlab implementation did same thing?  I think it is implementation issues. You also using memoization and paper seems to be using straight iteration. Not sure if this has anything to do with it. The best thing is to ask Authors to send you the Matlab code. Then you will know the truth :)

Comment: If remove chop than I get more problems.

Comment: Dear @Nasser I asked many times for the Matlab code but they do not give my email reply.

Comment: If such a numerical scheme takes hrs to finish using only 20 iterations as you show, then it is probably not a good one to start with !

Comment: One thing that's unclear from the paper is, how do they implement the integral? In your _Mathematica_ code you've relied on symbolic calculation, which makes the calculation rather slow. What if you turn to numeric integration? (Since the author of paper uses MATLAB, it's reasonable to guess they uses numeric integration. )